# Windows IIS Cipher Fix issue

Tags: windows, iis

Using windows 2008 R2 i'm trying to figure out how to fix the cipher issue that chrome is showing me:

[image]

I've been trying to find the solution but can't seem to get a clear answer on what to do. I've read that you have to get a new cert and others were you have to configure your crypto settings.  I've included my settings using IIS Crypt if that helps:

[image]
[image]

I've tried removing all the SHA ciphers but that only locked me out of using RDP. Is it just that I need to disable the right cipher?

**Update 5/12/2015**
From usr suggestion I updated my keys to  use SHA2 from GoDaddy and installed them.  All is working fine now.

Comment: Not really a programming question. Much more suited for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a SHA1-based certificate. [Chrome is phasing that out.](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) Obtain a new certificate. There's nothing about the server configuration that you can do to fix this.

Comment: My certs are from go daddy.  Would I need to generate a new key and then install or download from go daddy a new set of keys?

Comment: OK I just looked at my go-daddy account and my cert is SHA1 so I was able to change it to SHA2.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: I don't know anything about Go Daddy.